# How to validate the Tax / VAT Number field depending on whether it is a European country or not

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have a question about how to make the Tax / VAT Number field validate depending on the selected country in the the registration page and the configuration page.

Is there a way to do it in the admin configuration or should it be done with javascript?

Greetings and have a good day!

Angel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this documentation](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/tax/vat-validation.html), I think this is doing already what you need.

---

***LE:*** This refers only to the part where the taxes are adjusted based on the customer VAT ID. for the validation of the customer input in the VAT ID field, you will have to add your own validation.

Comment: Hi @diana-botean. Thank you very much for answering. I have tried to follow those steps as indicated. But when I try to edit the Tax / VAT Number field in the preferences that the client has, it doesn't validate it and I can put a random value. Do you think that for this case I would need javascript?

Comment: yes, i think that you will need that in order to validate that the VAT number is correct.

Comment: Ok, I'll get to work!
Thank you very much Diana!!

Comment: you're welcome! i suggest you mark the answer as solved if you found the answer you were looking for so others can see it too.